# How can I access a private data member 2D array in other methods within the class?

Tags: c++

This code is from my header file for a "Magic Square" generator.  I have tried to set the private member int**square through the constructor but when I attempt to return the array or print it through methods it returns a 2D array of different ints that it was not set to through the constructor.  What can I do to accsess the array through my methods.

```
class MagicSquare{
public:
    MagicSquare(int sideLenght);
    void printAllForms();
    void setsideLenght(int num);
    int**getMagicSquare();
    void printSquare(int** square);
    ~MagicSquare();
private:
    int sideLenght;
    int**square;
};

//constructor
MagicSquare :: MagicSquare(int sideLenght)
{
    this-> sideLenght = sideLenght;

//initialization of square and setting values to 0
int**square = new int*[sideLenght];
for(int i = 0; i !=sideLenght; i++)
    square[i] = new int[sideLenght];

for(int i = 0; i<sideLenght; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<sideLenght; j++)
    {
        square[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

//making the square magic
int row = sideLenght/2;
int col = sideLenght-1;
for(int i = 1; i<sideLenght*sideLenght+1;)
{
    if(row == -1 && col == sideLenght)
    {
        row++;
        col -= 2;
    }else{
        if(col == sideLenght)
            col = 0;
        if(row == -1)
            row = sideLenght-1;
    }
    if(square[row][col] != 0)
    {
        col -= 2;
        row++;
        continue;
    }else{
        square[row][col] = i;
        i++;
    }
    row--;
    col++;
}
}

MagicSquare :: ~MagicSquare(){
    if(square != NULL){
        for(int i = 0; i < sideLenght; ++i){
            delete[] square[i];
    }
delete[] square;
}
}

//print original and rotated 2D array
void MagicSquare :: printAllForms(){

for(int i = 0; i<sideLenght; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<sideLenght; j++){
        std::cout<<square[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int**rotatedSquare = new int*[sideLenght];
for(int x=0; x<4; x++){
    for(int i = 0; i<sideLenght; i++)
        square[i] = new int[sideLenght];

    for(int i=0; i<sideLenght; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<sideLenght; j++)
            rotatedSquare[i][j] = square[sideLenght-1-j][i];

    for(int i = 0; i<sideLenght; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<sideLenght; j++){
            std::cout<<rotatedSquare[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

}

void MagicSquare :: setsideLenght(int sideLenght){
    this-> sideLenght = sideLenght;
}

int** MagicSquare :: getMagicSquare(){
    return square;
}

//prints inputed 2D array
void MagicSquare :: printSquare(int**matrix){
    for(int i = 0; i<sideLenght; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<sideLenght; j++){
            std::cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Sorry if some of the code is formatted poorly I am new to stackoverflow and getting used to how it all works.
Thanks for the help

Comment: See: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you spent a little effort narrowing your problem into MCVE, you would probably solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`int**square = new int*[sideLenght];` in the constructor is creating a local variable `square` that hides the member (so the member is never set). Try `square = new int*[sideLenght];` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was really stuck there guess it just needed a second set of eyes.

Comment: i did I just have no reputation so it says it isn't visible